# Ford focus 1.6 diesel

Tags: ford, diesel, focus, fuel-injectors

Iv had 4 injectors replaced on my focus it ran fine then starting juddering. I took it the garage and they said that one of the new injectors had failed so we replaced that one again. It now runs rough when at low revs and starts juddering any suggestions. This was the original problem when it first went to the garage

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!